# Error: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Tags: c#

Fixed code, and still showing an error at the end. where  `public void displayCharacterDetails()` is.

```
public class Character
{
    private string char_name;
    private string char_descr;
    private byte char_level;
    private byte char_attack;
    private byte char_defence;
    private bool char_defeat;

    public Character(string name, string desc, byte level, byte attack, byte defence, bool defeat)
    {
        char_name = name;
        char_descr = "";
        char_level = level;
        char_attack = attack;
        char_defence = defence;
        char_defeat = defeat;
    }

    public string GetCharacterName()
    {
        return char_name;
    }

    public string GetCharacterDescription()
    {
        return char_descr;
    }

    public void SetCharacterDescription(string descr)
    {
        char_descr = descr;
    }

    public byte GetCharLevel()
    {
        return char_level;
    }

    public byte GetCharacterAttack()
    {
        return char_attack;
    }



    public byte GetCharacterDefence()
    {

        return char_defence;

    }

    public void resetCharacter(string name, string descr, byte level, byte attack, byte defence, bool defeat)
    {
        char_name = name;
        char_descr = "";
        char_level = level;
        char_attack = attack;
        char_defence = defence;
        char_defeat = defeat;
    }

    public void displayCharacterDetails() 

    { 

System.out.println("Character name: " + char_name); 

System.out.println("Character description" + char_descr); 

System.out.println("Character Level, Attack, Defence: " + char_level + " ,"+ char_attack + "  ,"+ char_defence);  
    }

}
```

Comment: looks like C#, why the tag java?

Comment: You must remove that trailing `;` from the ctor signature

Comment: @sanbhat - looks like java to me as it clearly Java, not C# coding standards... maybe attempt to directly copy-paste code from one to another?

Answer (score 2):

Replace the first line with :

```
public Character(string char_name, string char_desc, byte char_level, byte char_attack, byte char_defence, bool char_defeat)
```

Remove the `;` from the method declaration.

Also, you're missing a closing bracket here :

```
public byte getCharacterAttack() 

{
```

And also, you cannot name a method like a private field.

You have a field named `char_level` (as seen in your constructor with `this.char_level`) and a method with the same name here :

```
public byte char_level() 

{ 

return char_level; 

}
```

Rename the field, or the method to solve that.

And finally, in your constructor you have parameters named lkike `byte char_level` but you do `this.char_level = level;`. Replace that with `this.char_level = char_level;` for each parameters, or simply call each parameters only `byte level`.

---

So basically you should have this :

```
public class Character
{
    private string char_name;
    private string char_descr;
    private byte char_level;
    private byte char_attack;
    private byte char_defence;
    private bool char_defeat;

    public Character(string name, string desc, byte level, byte attack, byte defence,
                     bool defeat)
    {
        char_name = name;
        char_descr = "";
        char_level = level;
        char_attack = attack;
        char_defence = defence;
        char_defeat = defeat;
    }

    public string GetCharacterName()
    {
        return char_name;
    }

    public string GetCharacterDescription()
    {
        return char_descr;
    }

    public void SetCharacterDescription(string descr)
    {
        char_descr = descr;
    }

    public byte GetCharLevel()
    {
        return char_level;
    }

    public byte GetCharacterAttack()
    {
        return char_attack;
    }
}
```

I renamed your methods to follow C# conventions. I also removed the `this` keyword, it is not needed with those parameter names. Also please avoid putting too much whitespaces between your liens, it gets hard to read.

---

Or you could simply use C# properties :

```
public class Character
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Descr { get; set; }
    public byte Level { get; set; }
    public byte Attack { get; set; }
    public byte Defence { get; set; }
    public bool Defeat { get; set; }
{
```

and create new Characters like this :

```
Character character = new Character { Name = "the name", Descr = "the descr" } //etc.
```

Comment: @Cookiex VillageLife Just try with the code block I added at the end, you probably left out one of the gorillions mistake you made. The class compiles fine here. If it does not, check your namespace brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon `;` at the end.

```
public Character(string char_name, string char_desc, byte char_level, 
byte char_attack, 
byte char_defence, bool char_defeat);   //<< - remove the semicolon
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Character(string char_name, string char_desc, byte char_level,  
     byte char_attack, byte char_defence, bool char_defeat);
```

Is not how you declare a constructor.  You want this:

```
public Character(string char_name, string char_desc, byte char_level,  
     byte char_attack, byte char_defence, bool char_defeat)  
{  
   ...  
}
```

notice the removal of the semicolon `;`

Answer (score 0):

Your assignments look backwards, if you're passing in a parameter called char_name, and it looks like you have a class field called name, the line of code in the constructor should be this.name = char_name; The same problem exists in your set method.

Answer (score 0):

You put a semicolon after the constructor.